# Segments are not getting shifted / Cannot get correct arguments in Controller

Tags: laravel, localization

I am trying to implement a simple localization for an existing Laravel project.

Implementing Localization based on the following tutorial:
https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/

Here is the simplified code before localization implementation:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/poll/{poll_id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PollsController@view');
```

**PollsController@view**

```
public function view($poll_id){
    echo "poll_id: ".$poll_id;
}
```

**TEST**

URL: http://domain.name/poll/1

RESULT: poll_id: 1

Here are the simplified changes required for localization and the result I get:

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function() {    
    Route::get('/poll/{poll_id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PollsController@view');
});
```

**Middleware/SetLocale**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

PollsController@view remained unchanged.

Now, when I open the following URL (http://domain.name/en/poll/1), the result is:

RESULT: poll_id: en

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to ignore "'prefix' => '{locale}'" in controller or get arguments somehow shifted so that in the controller I still get **poll_id=1**, not **locale=en**?

PS. The easiest fix would be to add another argument to PollsController@view in the following way, but it does not smell well and then I would need to add locale argument to all functions, although I do not use it there:

```
public function view($locale, $poll_id){
    echo "poll_id: ".$poll_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your middleware you can tell the Route instance to forget that route parameter so it won't try to pass it to route actions:

```
public function handle($request, $next)
{
    app()->setLocale($request->route('locale'));

    // forget the 'locale' parameter
    $request->route()->forgetParameter('locale');

    return $next($request);
}
```