# How to set default locale without prefix in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I write a multilanguage application. I don't want to use locale prefix for the default language, so for example my URL structure should be like this:

```
https://example.com/about-us
https://example.com/contant
https://example.com/es/about-us
https://example.com/es/contant
https://example.com/de/about-us
https://example.com/de/contant
```

I use `Route::group` to group my routes by `locale` prefix:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-z]{2}'],
    'middleware' => 'setlocale'
], function () {
    Route::get('/{page}', [PageController::class, 'show'])->name('page');
});
```

in my middleware `setlocale` I set locale and prefix for URLs:

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (in_array($request->segment(1), ['es', 'de'])) {
            URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]);
            app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        } else {
            URL::defaults(['locale' => 'en']);
            app()->setLocale('en');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

and then my controller prints the data:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function show($lang, Page $page)
    {
        dd($page);
    }
}
```

This works well with `de` and `es` prefixes, but not without them - for English lang. I tried to copy `Route::get('/{page}', [PageController::class, 'show'])->name('page');` & paste it outside the `Route::group`, but then just one argument is passed to `PageController` and I get following error:

`Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PageController::show(), 1 passed in /Users/mati/Sites/laravel-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: you don't need to be passing the locale to the controllers ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594630/segments-are-not-getting-shifted-cannot-get-correct-arguments-in-controller/65594946#65594946 see if that helps you out

Comment: Thanks! however I still have a problem with `blade` files. Withour URL prefix I have following error: `Missing required parameter for [Route: homepage] [URI: {locale}] [Missing parameter: locale]. (View: /Users/mati/Sites/laravel-app/resources/views/partials/navbar.blade.php)`. My blade file contains `<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('homepage') }}">`

Comment: locale is a required parameter so something has to be set as its default or passed to the helpers

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to pass middleware for this specific route.

Comment: do you want if they hit a url containing the locale prefix to set that in the session then redirect them to a url without the locale prefix and use the session locale for the locale?

Comment: No. For SEO purposes I don't want to make any redirects once the language is chosen. When a user clicks the URL without prefix I want to serve him English content and all page URLs without any prefix. When he clicks URL with `/de` prefix, I want to keep him on this URL, generate all URLs on page with `/de` prefixes, and serve him German content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this.

Check that first slug is language prefix and is not default language then use it like prefix, else use nothing (null).

```
Route::prefix(parseLocale())->group(function () {
     Route::get('/{page}', [PageController::class, 'show'])->name('page');
}

function parseLocale(){
    $locale = request()->segment(1);
    $locales = config('translatable.locales');
    $default = config('app.fallback_locale');

    if ($locale !== $default && in_array($locale, $locales)) {
        app()->setLocale($locale);
        return $locale;
    }
}
```

In this example `config('translatable.locales')` is array of locales.

Then drop useless `$lang` param from controller:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Page $page)
    {
        dd($page);
    }
}
```

Comment: [tiger zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9174557/tiger-zhang) points out (I'm duplicating here as they posted it as an answer) that this will break when route caching is used.

Answer (score 0):

This full solution:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/contact
https://example.com/en/
https://example.com/en/contact
```

file 'routes/web.php'

```
if(!function_exists('parseLocale')) {
    function parseLocale()
    {
        $locale = request()->segment(1);
        if (in_array($locale, ['js', 'css'])) // for speed up :)
            return $locale;
        if (array_key_exists($locale, config('languages'))) {
            app()->setLocale($locale);
            return $locale;
        }
        app()->setLocale('es');  // this default locale
        return '/';
    }
}

/** Here route */
Route::prefix(parseLocale())->group(function () {

Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\PropertiesController::class, 'home']);
Route::get('/contact', function () {
        return view('contact');
    });

});
```

file 'config/languages.php'

```
<?php

return [
    'en' => [
        'display' => 'English',
    ],
    'es' => [
        'display' => 'Español',
    ],
];
```

files *.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ $init['lang'] }}">Home</a>
<a href="{{ $init['lang'] }}contact">Contact</a>
```

file 'app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php'

```
public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('*', function ($view) {
                $view->with('init', $this->loadTranslate());
        });
    }

 private function loadTranslate()
    {
$locale = app()->getLocale();
        if ($locale == 'es') $lang = '';
        else $lang = $locale . '/';

return [
            'lang' => '/' . $lang,
        ];
    }
```